# Using a carousel on home page or not?

Tags: carousel

I was thinking about the use of carousels in homepages, I have noticed a lot of web pages use and I really don't think they are useful sometimes, however I'm just a developer but I really like to do my homework and I decided to learn a big more about UX, problems come when I try to find a logic explanation why we should or not avoid this.

Comment: hi, yes exactly a jquery slider, but I'm talking about from a design and UX point of view, for sample, otoacademie.nl , basically is the slideshow at top

Comment: The slideshow on otoacademie.nl is more akin to an animated banner ad than a traditional carousel. The three views it presents are basically the same thing, just with three different tag lines.

Comment: See Yahoo's pattern explanation for this too: http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/selection/carousel.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whether you use a particular html feature or jquery widget or whatever really depends more on what problem you are trying to solve.

**Identify the problems to be solved, *then* design solutions to those problems.** Don't just grab solutions as seen elsewhere and then just use them.

---

Regarding [sliders (aka carousels)](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Carousel) ...

Use when your problem is:

- you have a large set of items to show, but want to let the user concentrate his or her attention only on a select few items at a time
- when you want to tease the user by letting him or her know that there are more items available than what is currently shown
- when you do not have enough space to show all items at once.

But only if:

- you have highly visual items to represent such as movie posters, album covers, products etc.

That is:

- do not use when the items are non-visual such as links to text articles, PDF documents etc
- do not use when the content linked to cannot be immediately identified by an image.

---

The fallback for non-js visitors would likely be to present a few thumbnails with a *more...* link (eg. *more news...* or *more featured products...*). That satisfies the problem requirements as detailed above.

Comment: +1. Also consider the fact that not all users will have javascript enabled, and in that case, how you should fall back for those users.

Comment: that is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks for taking the time